# Copy files but set filesize 0

Tags: robocopy

I need to copy files from a source directory to a target directory.

On the target directory I don't need the actual content. Its only important that the files exist.

How can I copy files but set them to have an empty (0 byte) content?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx), you can use this option:

> **/create** *Creates a directory tree and zero-length files only.*

This option does not copy the contents, but only the structure.